Definite integral is a conditionally convergent sum
I'm considering this peculiar (improper?) integral: let $r(x) = \lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor$, and $f(x) = (-1)^{r(x)} r(x)$. Consider:
$$\int_{0}^1 f(x) dx$$
I specifically machined the function $f(x)$ to get the integral to resemble a conditionally convergent alternating harmonic sum. Here's my solution to the value of the integral.
Partition the interval $(0,1)$ as $(1/2, 1), (1/3, 1/2), \dots, (1/(k+1), 1/k), \dots$. Now:
$$\int_{0}^1 f(x) dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\frac{1}{k+1}}^\frac{1}{k} (-1)^{r(x)} r(x) dx= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \int_{\frac{1}{k+1}}^\frac{1}{k} r(x) dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}$$
which (conditionally) converges to $\ln(2) - 1$.
My question then is: since the sum after the very first equality is conditionally convergent, and we can thus rearrange the terms to get a different result, does this mean the integral can have different values while still looking the same? When we write $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ we do not include any information about the "order" in which you compute the integral, whereas in the sum you sequentially add more and more terms. I also want to make it clear that in all other posts here that talk about conditional convergence and integrals, at least one of the limits of integration is $\pm \infty$ whereas in my case it is bounded.
I think understand the concept behind conditionally convergent series, but when something like this appears in an integral with bounded limits and a "clear" presence of some kind of definite signed area under $f(x)$, I get very thrown off.

The answer to this question very much depends on the kind of integral you want to consider:
In case of the Riemann-Integral, this is an improper integral. I.e. the integrand is not well-defined on the whole interval $[0,1]$, namely you have a pole at $0$. The Riemannian improper integral in this case is the defined to be the following limit if it exists:
$$\int_0^1 f(x) d x = \lim_{\alpha \to 0^+} \int_\alpha^1 f(x) dx.$$
This limit exists and therefore your function $f$ has the improper Riemann-integral $ \ln(2)−1$. Note that the limiting process we took very much has the "usual" order of adding the terms, hence we get the limit we expected.
In case of the Lebesgue-Integral, the story is a bit different. Namely there is no order when computing the limit. Rather we consider the positive and negative part of the function separately and only if both of them have a well-defined non-infinite integral, we say that our original function is integrable. This is not the case, as both the positive and negative parts of our function have infinite integral. So $f$ is not Lebesgue-integrable.
It may seem from this discussion that the Lebesgue-integral is weaker in some sense. But in fact the opposite is the case. Not caring about the "order" in which we integrate is in fact a feature, not a bug. For example the Cantor-Function, which is $1$ on all rational numbers and $0$ everywhere else is not Riemann-integrable but is Lebesgue-integrable.

Is the pole at 1 or at 0? I thought the integral would have to be $\lim_{a\to 0+} \int_{a}^1 f(x) dx$. $f(1) = -1$, or am i mistaken?

Yes, you are correct, I will edit the answer.
